# Error implemented a specific factorial design in Minitab (default generators)

Tags: experiment-design, minitab

I'm intending to implement the following factorial design

I wish to obtain this alias structure - with a 2^(5-2) factorial design.

```
I+ACE+BDE+ABCD
A+CE+ABDE+BCD
B+ABCE+DE+ACD
C+AE+BCDE+ABD
D+ACDE+BE+ABC
E+AC+BD+ABCDE
AB+BCE+ADE+CD
AD+CDE+ABE+BC
```

I've obtained this (the alias structure) by hand, using the design generators I=ACE and I=BDE. I've controlled my alias structure and confirmed it is the correct one.

However, using Stat->DOE->Create factorial design-> 2 level design (specify generators)

and using 5 factors

And subsequently using

Default generators: ACE, BDE

Gives the error "Block are aliased with the mean".

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You didn't mention blocks in your description of the design. At a wild guess, did you accidentally ask for blocks when setting up the design in Minitab?

Comment: Thanks alot for replying!

Come to think of it - I did. But there are only two options - either "Add factors to the base design by listing their generators" Which I believe is not what I want to do

Or to "Define blocks by listing their generators". 

Is there a trick with adding factors so I will end up with the desired design? Or is this done in another way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Minitab. But I noticed just now you selected '2 level design (default generators)'. Isn't there another option for defining your own generators? 'Default' is presumably the generators Minitab picks. Or perhaps try experimenting with "Add factors to the base design by listing their generators".

Comment: Does [this](http://www.minitab.com/en-US/support/answers/answer.aspx?id=314&langType=1033) help? ('2-level factorial (specify generators)'.)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I meant I used 2 level factorial (specify generators). I just mixed the english words Specify and Default together! Sorry about that

Comment: I'd guess then that picking "Add factors to the base design by listing their generators" & giving something like A=CE & B=DE should do it.